# What SQL query would produce these results?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, pivot

Given this data:

```
Name       Property   Value
---------- ---------- ----------
Bob        Hair       Red       
Bob        Eyes       Blue      
Fred       Hair       Brown     
Fred       Height     Tall
```

what SQL would be required to produce these results?

```
Property   Bob        Fred
---------- ---------- ----------
Hair       Red        Brown     
Eyes       Blue             
Height                Tall
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008, but a generic solution would be nice.

Comment: a pivot query, which not all DBs support.

Comment: Hava a look at MSSQL Pivot: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: Using SQL Server 2008, but was looking for a generic answer.  After seeing the answers, I'm thinking that a generic answer is probably not the best way to go.

Comment: @JeffRoe Are you going to know the names ahead of time? meaning will you know `Bob` or `Fred`?

Comment: Yes, I know 'Bob' and 'Fred'.

Comment: But are those the only values you want to turn into columns?

Comment: Yes, those are the only values to be turned into columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using but this is a *pivot*. You can use an aggregate function and a `CASE` expression in all databases:

```
select property,
  max(case when name='Bob' then value else '' end) Bob,
  max(case when name='Fred' then value else '' end) Fred
from yourtable
group by property
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50ce5/3)

If you are using a database that has a `PIVOT` function (SQL Server 2005+/Oracle 11g+), then your code will be similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
  select property, name, value
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for name in (Bob, Fred)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50ce5/5)

The above queries work great, if you know the name values ahead of time, but if you don't then you will want to use dynamic sql:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(name) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT property,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select property, name, value
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(value)
                for name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/50ce5/7)

All three will produce the same result:

```
| PROPERTY |  BOB |  FRED |
---------------------------
|     Eyes | Blue |       |
|     Hair |  Red | Brown |
|   Height |      |  Tall |
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the old-fashioned way, of course assuming that each (Name, Property) is unique:

```
SELECT Properties.Property, Bob.Value, Fred.Value
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT Property
FROM myTable
) Properties
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT Property, Value
FROM myTable
WHERE Name = 'Bob'
) Bob ON Properties.Property = Bob.Property
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT Property, Value
FROM myTable
WHERE Name = 'Fred'
) Fred ON Properties.Property = Fred.Property
```

Of course you can only do this if you know the columns ahead of time. You could make and execute dynamic SQL if you did not, but this is not without its issues.

Depending on your RDBMS you may be able to use a pivot query instead, which will simplify the syntax (or make it possible if you have an unknown number/names of people)